# Assertj-Swagger PropertyType mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-boot-test

When running my swagger definition test I get the following error below:

```
Stack trace:
 org.assertj.core.error.AssertJMultipleFailuresError: 
Multiple Failures (1 failure)
-- failure 1 --
[Checking response schema of response '200' of 'GET' operation of path '/api/controller/method/{param}'] 
Expecting:
 <io.swagger.models.properties.ByteArrayProperty@bf0f8c09>
to be exactly an instance of:
 <io.swagger.models.properties.StringProperty>
but was an instance of:
 <io.swagger.models.properties.ByteArrayProperty>
at ConsumerDrivenValidator.validateProperty(ConsumerDrivenValidator.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at io.github.robwin.swagger.test.ConsumerDrivenValidator.validateSwagger(ConsumerDrivenValidator.java:90)
    at io.github.robwin.swagger.test.SwaggerAssert.satisfiesContract(SwaggerAssert.java:111)
    at io.github.robwin.swagger.test.SwaggerAssert.satisfiesContract(SwaggerAssert.java:123)
    at com.myapp.api.documentation.MyTestClass.MyTestMethod(MyTestClass.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Here's the content of my yaml file:

```
'/api/controller/method/{param}':
    get:
      tags:
        - my-controller
      summary: photo
      operationId: photoUsingGET
      produces:
        - image/jpeg
      parameters:
        - name: param
          in: path
          description: param
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: string
            format: byte
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
        '404':
          description: Not Found
      security:
        - apiKey: []
      deprecated: false
```

My method accepts a parameter int and returns an image in a form of byte array `public @ResponseBody byte[] myMethod(@PathVariable Long param);`. Upon reading [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/), my file has the correct content. I really have no idea what went wrong with my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenAPI 2.0, responses that are files must have `type: file`.

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: file
```

More info: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-responses/#response-that-returns-a-file

Comment: But is that compatible with byte array return type?

Comment: `type: file` is usually handled as a binary stream or byte array. Can you try and see if this fixes your issue?